# React Native Converting JSON objects to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I fetch some data from the server and the data response comes in this form

```
    [
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1495daa062304c60c7b0",
        "weightTracking": 97,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 12"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb14eadaa062304c60c7b1",
        "weightTracking": 96,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 13"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb161ddaa062304c60c7b2",
        "weightTracking": 95,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 14"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1c6cdaa062304c60c7b3",
        "weightTracking": 94,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 15"
    },
]
```

I want to be able to use this data in my app like that

```
              data={{
            labels: ['Nov 12', 'Nov 13', 'Nov 14', 'Nov 15'],
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [
                  97,
                  96,
                  95,
                  94,
                ],
              },
            ],
          }}
```

Like [weightTracking] , [weightTrackingDate] in Javascript or react-native 
how can I do that? is it possible to do that?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?  Why are you decoupling the weightTrackingDate into labels and the weightTracking into datasets:data?

Comment: It's worth noting that this problem isn't really related to react/react-native. It's a generic javascript task.

Comment: Use for loop and push the 2 values to 2 different arrays. What trouble are you facing with your code?

Comment: you can format the data on the client side but I would recommend to adjust on the backend if you have access to it

Comment: you have to json decode the data, it will return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// assuming that data fetched from the server is inside the variable called 'response'
const response = [
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1495daa062304c60c7b0",
        "weightTracking": 97,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 12"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb14eadaa062304c60c7b1",
        "weightTracking": 96,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 13"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb161ddaa062304c60c7b2",
        "weightTracking": 95,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 14"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1c6cdaa062304c60c7b3",
        "weightTracking": 94,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 15"
    },
]

const labels = [];
const datasets = [];

response.forEach(item => {
  labels.push(item.weightTrackingDate)
  datasets.push(item.weightTracking)
})

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    data: datasets,
  }]
}
```

Edit: instead of a straightforward answer, I'll add some comments too:

As @byxor stated, it's not at all related to React Native. It's a simple JavaScript task. React Native uses JavaScript but don't get those two confused. Arrays, objects, loops, etc are a feature of the language, not the framework.

You could also use a for() loop for this, instead of using forEach, but it's totally up to you. It mostly comes down to code readability.

Comment: thanks very much it's working but the datasets comes in this form `97969594` I want it to be like this `97,96,95,94` how can i do that?

Comment: @mohamedadel I don't understand, I thought the datasets came in as an array of MongoDB records? Please elaborate on that

Comment: Perfect it's working. there was something wrong on my end. but this is exactly what i wanted thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the data in the format you specified

```
let originalArray = <Your array>;
let data = originalArray.reduce((newObj, currentElement) => {
    newObj.labels.push(currentElement.weightTrackingDate);
    newObj.datasets[0].data.push(currenElement.weightTracking);
    return newObj;
}, { labels: [], datasets: [{data: []}] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve this:

```
let arr = [
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1495daa062304c60c7b0",
        "weightTracking": 97,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 12"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb14eadaa062304c60c7b1",
        "weightTracking": 96,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 13"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb161ddaa062304c60c7b2",
        "weightTracking": 95,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 14"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dcb1c6cdaa062304c60c7b3",
        "weightTracking": 94,
        "weightTrackingDate": "Nov 15"
    },
];
console.log(arr);
let outarr = [];
let labeles = [];
let dataset = [];
arr.forEach( e => {
    labeles.push(e.weightTracking);
    dataset.push(e.weightTrackingDate);
})
console.log("----------------------");
console.log(labeles);
console.log(dataset);

let data={};

data.labels = labeles;
data.datasets = {}
data.datasets.data = dataset;

console.log(data);
```